# ELI5 Step-by-step explanation of the code used to render a 3D model

Tags: xna

I've read books and web pages on rendering a 3D model in XNA, and I've got the code to render a simple model with textures, but can somebody explain to me what each line of code does, step by step? There are loads of vaguely named methods and I think it's best for me if I actually understand what the code does as well as memorising the code.

Comment: I have no idea what the code you've written looks like.  How am I supposed to explain it to you?